# How to pass Null\Void instead of an array?

Tags: java, parameters, arguments, invocation

Having some `invokeMethod` that takes in `(java.lang.String method_name,                                      Object[] params, Class[] params_classes)` How would you invoke some method with signature like `void MyMethod()`?

Comment: Which `invokeMethod` are you referring to? There's only one method by that name in Java6 (on `javax.script.Invocable`), and it doesn't have that signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `new Object[0]` and `new Class[0]` to specify empty arrays.